# Normal field continuous

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=1\}$ and let $f:S_1\to S_2$ with $c:I\to S.$ Furthermore, $df(p)(X)=\dfrac{d}{dt}f(c(t))\Bigg|_{t=t_0}$ and $c(t_0)=p$ with $c'(t_0)=X.$ Calculate $dN(p)(X)$ if $p=(x,y,z)\in S.$

Comment: What are $S_1$ and $S_2$?

Comment: @Ted are surfaces...

Comment: Did you try something or something?